# scheduleで実行時間を自動化し、スクレイピング

Tags: python, web-scraping

毎日一定の時刻に、特定のURLからjsonを取得しDataframeに保存する、ということがやりたいです。
テストとして１分置きでの取得条件で書いてみたのですが、実行すると以下のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
TypeError: get_all_reviews() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

スクリプト（schedule部分のスクリプトを削除すると、正常に実行されます）

```py
def get_all_reviews(url):
    rvw_list_text = []
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(i,'searching')
        i += 1        
        res = requests.get(url)
        res_json = json.loads(res.text)
        data = res_json.get('data')
        for d in data:
            rvw_list_text.append(d)

        #dataが殻でなければ
        if data !=[]:
            paging = dict(res_json.get('paging'))
            next_page = str(paging['next'])
            url = next_page
        else:
            break


    return rvw_list_text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx"
    rvw_list_text = get_all_reviews(url)


#AM10:30にjobを実行
#schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(get_all_reviews)
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_all_reviews)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_all_reviews, url='何かのURL')` としてみたらどうでしょう？ [How can I pass arguments to the job function?](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-the-job-function)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、同様のエラーが出てしまうようです。

Comment: Windows10の`Python 3.7.5`と`schedule 0.6.0`では、コメントした方法で登録と呼び出しは行われて、1回目の`requests.get`処理までは出来ました。何か環境か版数の問題かも。

Comment: 説明不足ですみません。`request.get`はでき、一応リストは取得できているようなのですが、上記のエラーが表示され、`schadule`で設定した「１分置きの取得」ができない状況です。

Comment: `res_json = ...`以下をコメントにして、sleepを挟んで同じurlを5回`get`後に終了するように試したら、「1分置きの取得」も出来ています。あと`if __name__ == ...`の部分も外しています。それらの何かが影響を与えているのかもしれません。その辺を削って毎分呼び出されるようにしておいてから、少しずつ処理を追加して試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: すみません。超初心者でして、「res_json = ...以下をコメントにして、sleepを挟んで同じurlを5回get後に終了する」のコードがわからず、コードを教えていただくことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**判明して全体を改訂**
その後調べていて幾つか判明しました。以下のものです。

- `data`が空かどうかの判定方法違い
  `if data != []:`だけで判定していたのは間違いで先に`is not None`で調べておいた方が良い
  `if data is not None and data != []:`のようにする
- 次ページの url を設定する処理でも例外が発生することがある
  その3行の処理を`try`,`except`で囲む  例外時は`break`する
- `for d in data:`処理も`is not None`で調べておいた方が良い
  `if data is not None:`の時に呼び出す
- 他にも何か問題が発生した場合は、`try`,`except`で囲む

対策結果は以下になります。

```
import functools
import time
import schedule
import requests
import json

def get_all_reviews(url):
    rvw_list_text = []
    i = 1
    while True:
        print(i,'searching')
        i += 1        
        res = requests.get(url)
        res_json = json.loads(res.text)
        data = res_json.get('data')
        if data is not None:
            for d in data:
                rvw_list_text.append(d)

        if data is not None and data != []:
            try:
                paging = dict(res_json.get('paging'))
                next_page = str(paging['next'])
                url = next_page
            except:
                break
        else:
            break

    return rvw_list_text

# ここはコメントアウト
#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx"
#    rvw_list_text = get_all_reviews(url)

#AM10:30にjobを実行
#schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(get_all_reviews)

# 以下のパラメータに url= を追加。何かのurl は有効なurlに変える
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_all_reviews, url='何かのurl')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
↑を実行したところ、
`1 searching
2 searching
3 searching
4 searching
5 searching
1 searching
2 searching
3 searching
4 searching
5 searching
1 searching
2 searching
3 searching
4 searching
5 searching
・・・`
のように、処理が永遠に繰り返されてしまうのですが、何かおかしいでしょうか。

初歩的な質問ばかりで申し訳ありません。

Comment: それが正しい動きです。1～5が1秒おきに、5と1の間は55秒程度間隔が出来るはずです。1分毎に呼び出されるというのは、こういう動きを示します。それがわかったら、コメントアウトしていた部分を少しづつ「まとまった処理単位」で戻して、どこで問題が発生するかを探るわけです。

Comment: すみません、削除いたしました。

Comment: この質問はこれで完了として、実際のページでの処理については、関連する場所 [開発者サポート](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) や [Developer Community Forum](https://developers.facebook.com/community/) において質問する方が良いと思われます。

Comment: 関連サイトで質問してみます、本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`get_all_reviews()` の定義で引数を取るようにしているので、

```
def get_all_reviews(url):
                    ~~~
```

呼び出す際には URL の指定が必要なのではないでしょうか？

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_all_reviews("https://graph.facebook.com/xxx"))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。今度は以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。
`TypeError: the first argument must be callable`